# Add data from client side to Apollo?

Tags: apollo

Im trying to get my head around Apollo with React. How can I add state to my local Apollo store?

I'm using Meteor. It provides a function on the client side to test if a user is logged in and return their id if they are with `Meteor.userId()`. I need to access this state in a number of different components.

Here is my client file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloLink, from } from 'apollo-link';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

import App from '../../../imports/ui/App/App';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: Meteor.absoluteUrl('graphql'),
});

const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    const token = Accounts._storedLoginToken();
    operation.setContext(() => ({
        headers: {
            'meteor-login-token': token,
        },
    }));
    return forward(operation);
});

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: from([authLink, httpLink]),
    cache,
});

const ApolloApp = () => (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
);

Meteor.startup(() => {
    render(<ApolloApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Register APIs (server):

```
import { createApolloServer } from 'meteor/apollo';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import merge from 'lodash/merge';

import GroupsSchema from '../../api/groups/Groups.graphql';
import GroupsResolvers from '../../api/groups/resolvers';

import UsersSchema from '../../api/users/Users.graphql';
import UsersResolvers from '../../api/users/resolvers';

// Comment find

const typeDefs = [GroupsSchema, UsersSchema];
const resolvers = merge(GroupsResolvers);

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

createApolloServer({ schema });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First,** here is the simplest example from the docs on how to **read** from the cache:

```
client.query({ query: gql`{ hello }` }).then(console.log);
```

Read more about it here: [Apollo Client - Basic Operations](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html#basic-operations)

Here is the explanation how to **write** directly to the cache:
[Apollo Client - writeQuery and writeFragment](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/caching.html#writequery-and-writefragment)

**Second,** these are good for multiple scenarios. But **what you probably really want** is to wrap your components with HOC that will execute queries that read from the cache and put the results on your component's `props`. It's very simple to accomplish with the functions provided by Apollo Client.

You can find a great explanation and examples here: [Apollo Client - Queries Basics](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#basics)

For queries that read only from the local cache, use `FetchPolicy: 'cache-only'`
Read about it here: [Apollo Client - Queries - options.fetchPolicy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy)

**Third,** For many scenarios, like the one you mentioned, the two above should be enough. If you need **more control managing your local state**, then there is the new `apollo-link-state`.

With it you can write custom resolvers on the client that will deal directly with the local cache without reaching to the server. It let's you execute complex operations that are partially resolved on the server and partially by the client.

Read more about it here: [Apollo Link - Manage your local data with Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html)